# A Proof of Series of A Product of Fourier Coefficients Converges Absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, proof-explanation

[image]
I am reading Rudin's RCA. In the section 4.26, Rudin says the Parseval theorem asserts
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n)\overline{\hat{g}(n)}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt$$
for all $f, g\in L^2(T)$.
Then Rudin says that the series on the left side of above equality converges absolutely.
How to justify this? If the case that $f=g$ holds, clearly the series converges absolutely.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\ell^2$ is a Hilbert space, with inner product $\langle \hat{f}(n),\hat{g}(n)\rangle=\sum_n\hat{f}(n)\overline{\hat{g}(n)}.$ Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, 
$$  \sum_n\left|\hat{f}(n)\overline{\hat{g}(n)}\right|=\langle |\hat{f}(n)|,|\hat{g}(n)|\rangle\leq\left(\sum\limits_n|\hat{f}(n)|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum\limits_n|\hat{g}(n)|^2\right)^{1/2}<\infty,$$ since $f$ and $g$ are in $L^2(\mathbb{T}),$ so the sums of their Fourier series coefficients converge in $\ell_2.$